# Writing a multiline if in React (JSX)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm making a very simple react component "Clicker" that is rendered to App.

All it is is an H1 with a random number after the 2 that is generated upon clicking the button.

I want it to display winner if the chosen number is 7.

I can't work out why my if statement isnt working in this case. I have written ternary if's here before and it is okay, I must be missing something small for it not to work?

Thank you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Clicker extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        super(props);
        this.state = { num: num };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick(e) {
        this.setState({winner:0});
    }

    render() {
        let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        return(
         <div>
        <h1>Number is {num}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Random Number</button>
        if (this.state.num === 7) {
            <h2>Winner!</h2>
        }
         </div>   
        );
    }
}[website render][1]


export default Clicker;
```

Comment: For your reference, this is known as "conditional rendering".

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` in your render function starts a block of JSX.

Everything in JSX is compiled to **HTML** unless it is inside `{ ... }` in which case it is treated as a JavaScript expression.

You didn't put the `if` inside `{ ... }` (so it is treated as text to go in the HTML) and even if you did, it would be a statement, not an expression, and thus not valid there.

---

If you want to use an `if`, you need to do it outside the JSX, and use `{ ... }` to put the result into the JSX:

```
let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let winner = "";
if (this.state.num === 7) {
    winner = (<h2>Winner!</h2>);
}

return (
   <div>
      <h1>Number is {num}</h1>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Random Number</button>
      {winner}
   </div>   
);
```

---

If you want to use it inline, then you need an *expression* and you need to put it in `{ ... }`

```
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Random Number</button>
      {this.state.num === 7 ? (<h2>Winner!</h2>) : ""}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `{` and `}` around your embedded JavaScript for it to work. This tells the JSX compiler an expression is coming up. `&&` and `??` are operators that return the righthand value if the lefthand one is true.

```
    <h1>Number is {num}</h1>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Random Number</button>
    {(this.state.num === 7) && <h2>Winner!</h2>}
     </div>   
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `if` inside braces or even better

```
{this.state.num === 7 && <h2>Winner!</h2>}
```